# Python list comprehension fails with syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was doing excercise no.3 from http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/15b-python-pushups/, I made the code work but was wondering if it was possible to do it in fewer lines? Here is my solution:

```
los = [] # short for list of strings
while True:
   s = input()
   if s == '###': break
   los += s.lower().split() # making a list of lower case words from the input     sentences
test = []
for x in los:
   test += str(los.count(x)) # made a new list of the frequency of each word
a = test.index(max(test)) # variable a provides the location of them most frequent word
print (los[a]) # we know the position of the most frequent string, so find it in los.
# a is not needed but it looks neater
```

So this part in particular is what i'm not happy with:

```
    for x in los:
       test += str(los.count(x))
```

I want to re write it like:

```
test += str(list.count(x)) for x in los
```

but it tells me invalid syntax..any tips?

Comment: use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ this type of questions\

Comment: Just put this after the while loop: `print(max(los, key=los.count))`

Comment: @grc thanks that worked but I don't understand how that line actually works (at all), could you please explain it?

Comment: @VimalKarsan the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function takes a list (or other iterable) and returns the largest element. When a key is specified, it returns the element with the largest key. So in this case, `max` calls `los.count()` on each item in `los` and returns the item with the highest count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
  # No need for test = []
  test = [str(list.count(x)) for x in los]
```